# Linux single find command within thousands of directories

Tags: linux, find

I have to search through about 7,000 directories and determine the number of PDFs modified last month grouped by the type of PDF, which is in a MySQL database.  The folder structure is...

```
/folder/to/FORMID/*.pdf
/folder/to/FORMID/*.pdf
/folder/to/FORMID/*.pdf
/folder/to/FORMID/*.pdf
```

Currently I'm running...

```
find "/folder/to/FORMID/" "/folder/to/FORMID/" "/folder/to/FORMID/"  -name '*.pdf' -mtime +31 -mtime -51 | wc -l
```

except with up to 4,000 directories as parameters.  This isn't returning what I know to be accurate results.

Is this the most efficient way to do this or is there another linux command I can use?

Comment: You say you want to do this within the last 30 days, why is your find +31 and then -51?  That is GREATER than 31 days and LESS than 51 days.

Comment: @mdpc - Updated, not the last 30 days, the last month

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't just start your find at the top level directory?  `find /folder/ -name '*.pdf' ...`?  I don't understand why you think you need to list each directory individually?  You can use additional operators if you want to set a min/max depth, or match a portion of the path.

Answer (score 1):

Find should work appropriately. Since the command is running, I'm assuming it's not a too many / too long arguments error. Give that, it may be a bug in `find`. There are many options that can reasonably work around that. Here are two:

- Scripting instead of using find directly
- Using `args -n $NUM` to check $NUM directories per run of `find`

  cat directory_list | xargs -n 30 -IX find X -mtime +31 -mtime -51 -name '*.pdf'

I'm assuming that you have many subdirectories that you intend to not read, hence not specifying a single higher-level directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file which containts the names of the directories to search, you could do this shell/find combination:

```
for i in `cat LIST_OF_DIR_NAMES.TXT`; do find ${i} -mtime +31 -mtime -51 -name '*.pdf' ; done | wc -l
```

This will run find on each directory in LIST_OF_DIR_NAMES.TXT and give you the total files found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want PDFs modified WITHIN the last 30 days, wouldn't you do something like this:

```
 find dir1 dir2 ... dirn -name '*.pdf' -mtime -31 -print
```

Comment: The problem is not the time frame, I have that part successful.  The problem is that when I add this many paths is screws up.

Comment: If you have 'spaces' or special characters in the filename when the wc command might have problems.

Comment: Also, remember time increases as you run the commands, thus if files are on the cusp of a number of days increase it could vary depending on how long things take to do a find.